# How to create a vertical menu with changing content on other side in WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2019

I tried to create a vertical menu with MenuItem control. But, it doesn't give me the same picture as what I want. I am able to create the below menu:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2N25T.png)

But, the result I want is something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4spl.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a MenuItem control, use a [TabControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol?view=net-5.0) instead, with its `TabStripPlacement` property set to `Left`, to get the result that you want.

Here's a starting point for you:

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyHeaderTemplate">
            <Grid Background="#437C97" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabItem},Path=Header}" 
                           FontSize="18" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Left" Margin="10,5" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabItem Header="Add Project" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource MyHeaderTemplate}" >
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock FontSize="32" Text="Add Project stuff goes here"/>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Add Supplier" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource MyHeaderTemplate}">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock FontSize="32" Text="Add Supplier stuff goes here"/>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Add Item" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource MyHeaderTemplate}">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock FontSize="32" Text="Add Item stuff goes here"/>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Add Contact" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource MyHeaderTemplate}">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock FontSize="32" Text="Add Contact stuff goes here"/>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Add Order" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource MyHeaderTemplate}">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock FontSize="32" Text="Add Order stuff goes here"/>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

The resulting UI will look like this:
[image]

You can research the rest to get the final result that you want.

Comment: Thank you @Tam Bui, I will try this with TabControl and will update here.